# Embedding a dynamically created image during run-time using Swiftmailer in Symfony2

Tags: image, symfony, embedding, swiftmailer, dynamically-generated

There is a route in my Symfony2 app that generates a png-image. The route works, and there are Twig templates using and embedding this png-image during run-time.

Now I am trying to embed this same image in an e-mail that I would like to send with Swiftmailer. But when I do so, it leads to this "internal server error":

> ErrorException: Warning:
>   fopen(http:// localhost/app/web/app_dev.php/autograph/15.png): failed
>   to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server
>   Error

If I remove the dynamically generated image, the mail is sent correctly. Another image with a fixed url is also embeded in the email, and works just fine (this is the company logo).

This is how I include the PNG-image (this is just a fragment of my controller action):

```
  $auth_url = 
  $this
    ->container
    ->get('router')
    ->generate('autograph_route', array('id' => $id), true);
  $auth_img = \Swift_Image::fromPath($auth_url);
  $auth_cid = $message->embed($auth_img);

  $message
   ->setSubject($subject)
   ->setFrom($data['fromAddress'])
   ->setTo($data['toAddress'])
   ->setBody($this->renderView('mailBundle:Mail:mail.html.twig', 
     array
     (
      'data' => $data,
      'logo_cid' => $logo_cid,
      'autograph_cid' => $auth_cid
     )
    ))
    ->setContentType("text/html");
```

Then in my Twig template I include the image like this:

```
<img src="{{ logo_cid }}"/> <!-- works -->
<img src="{{ autograph_cid }}"/> <!-- causes error -->
```

Typing the generated url ("http:// localhost/app/web/app_dev.php/autograph/15.png") in the browser, makes the dynamically generated image appear correctly. Headers are set to: "image/png".

How can I make the image appear in my mail as well?

**ADDED:**

The error log shows two critical errors that occur if and only if the autograph image is included in the mail:

```
request.CRITICAL: UnexpectedValueException: The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given. (uncaught exception) at C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\app\cache\dev\classes.php line 3947 [] []
```

and

```
request.CRITICAL: Exception thrown when handling an exception (Twig_Error_Runtime: An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template ("Node "1" does not exist for Node "Twig_Node".") in "TwigBundle::layout.html.twig".) [] []
```

Comment: And what does the server log tell you when the error 500 happens?

Comment: @cheesemacfly Two errors; but in this case I can't really understand neither of them... See my addition.